# Within a Python context manager, prevent people from running PySpark queries

Tags: python, pyspark, dynamic, contextmanager

I would like to create a Python context manager that you would use in this way:

```py
with ContextManager() as cm:
    ...
```

and I would like to make it so within the context manager, any attempt of the user to interact with PySpark should return an exception. So, assuming `df` is a PySpark DataFrame, the following code:

```py
with ContextManager() as cm:
    ... 
    df.count()
```

should throw an exception. Similarly, users shouldn't be allowed to create new DataFrames or RDDs. I suspect I need to dynamically redefine some of the methods of the SparkSession in my `ContextManager`'s `__enter__` method, and reset them on `__exit__`, but I'm not sure what's the simplest way of doing that to achieve my goal.

I'm not looking to obtain a strong security guarantee, I'm aware that anything I do in Python can be dynamically changed at runtime by users of the library. But I'm in a situation where doing direct PySpark operations in the `ContextManager` block is almost certainly a user misunderstanding, so I would like to detect it and let the user know that they probably didn't mean to do this.